# for loop skipping a line

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm super new to c# and programming in general.  I'm trying to do some exercises online to familiarize myself with the basics of the language before I start school next month. 
  I've written a super simple program and I just can't understand why it's doing what it's doing and I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere. Here's the code.

```
        int i, j, rows;

        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("Display the pattern like right angle triangle which repeat a number in a row:\n");
        Console.Write("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        Console.Write("Input number of rows : ");
        rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                Console.Write("{0}", i);
                Console.Write("\n");

        }
```

All this program is suppose to do is a simple pyramid with the same number.

My question is that in the second for loop it writes `i` but then it re-evaluates `j++` and `j<=` instead of writing `\n` until the end of the last run of the loop.  I don't understand why?  The program works but I am not understanding why. Isn't the for loop always suppose to execute everything in it unless you break it?

thanks and sorry for the very novice question but its driving me nuts!

Comment: This isn't Python, indentation means nothing. When meant to be executed together, you wrap the two lines under your inner loop in braces to make them into a loop body. Otherwise, a loop body is only a single statement. As written, the second Console.Write applies to i, not j.

Comment: @AlexJolig please never edit the code in a question where you're "fixing" the mistake that is the crux of the question at hand.  The OP clearly had some confusion about indentation and your "fixing" completely breaks this entire Q&A.

Comment: @KirkWoll Fine!

Comment: The indentation has no bearing on the question. The question was regarding for loops, not how to format code on stack overflow

Comment: @RabidPenguin, regardless, the OP's original formatting was important for conveying his perception of the logic of his code.

Comment: @RabidPenguin, furthermore, after reviewing the question again, I think you are incorrect, and Anthony is right.

Comment: You may be correct with changing the indentation of the for loop. I was more referring to adding the variable declaration to the code block.

Comment: @RabidPenguin, yeah, was (I think obviously) explicitly referring to the indentation.  If I was unclear, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses so quickly. I didn't even notice that the second for didn't have curly braces! I didn't realize you could write a for workout them, thanks so much!

Comment: @Eshez, arguably, the world would be a better place if you couldn't. ;)  (but that gets into some highly fraught subjective territory.)

Comment: @Eshez Since you're new in SO (apparently), remember to check the answer as the right answer, in order to encourage one to help another.

Comment: Ok. Yeah I've only been a member for about an hour now. I want to give credit where credit is due and will pay it forward in the future.

Comment: Due to the way your code was formatted I decided to update my question to provide some additional information about the for loop. No need to change the correct answer or anything, just thought you'd be interested.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Does indentation has an impact on logical flow of execution in python?

Comment: @RBT yes https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+indentation+important+in+python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop will execute everything in its scope. Without using { } the scope of a for loop is the next line after it. To execute more than one command you need to put them in curly braces like so:

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}", i);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

It's generally best practice to always have the { } for readability and to easily update the loop if needed. Though you could write your for loop like so and it would be perfectly readable.

```
for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}", i);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

The above code will do the same thing keeping the second for loop in the scope of the first.

As an aside, I noticed you declared your variables outside of the for loop, being new to programming you may not be aware of certain features of the for loop.

You can declare your iterator right in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
```

In most cases it's better to declare your iterator in the for loop like this as it gives 'i' the same scope as the for loop.

Another neat feature of the for loop is that all the options between the semi-colons are actually optional. So for instance, if you declared your  iterator outside the for loop you can omit it in the for loop:

```
int i = 1;
for (; i<= rows; ++i)
```

You can omit any part or all of it even:

```
for (;;) // a perfectly valid for loop that will loop forever.
```

You can even have multiple iterators:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5; ++i, ++j)
```

Answer (score 4):

In programming every statement have a scope block in which it run.
By default for loop have only one statement scope that just comes after it. If we wanted to run more then one statement in for loop scope then we use curly braces {} to define the code block.

in your case you need to use curly braces like this to run both statements.

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
   Console.Write("{0}", i);
   Console.Write("\n");
}
```

**its best programming practices to used braces {} in all you conditional and looping constructs. It make easy to read and understand the code.**

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation that in every iteration of inner `for` loop both `Console.Write` statements will get executed is wrong:

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    Console.Write("{0}", i); //inner for loop scope starts and ends on this statement
```

There is no curly brace after inner `for` loop. So, by default ONLY first statement encountered after for statement will be treated under the scope of inner `for` loop.

Outer `for` loop has a curly brace as shown below:

```
for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{//outer for loop scope starts here
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        Console.Write("{0}", i);
    Console.Write("\n");
}//outer for loop scope ends here
```

So in every iteration of outer for loop the whole inner `for` loop and the `Console.Write("\n");` will execute.

As a general practice, if you have only one statement to execute inside your for loop then you indent it with a tab as depicted in your code snippet as well.